# Stop Servlet context from initializing in init method

Tags: java, servlets, servletcontextlistener

I have a servlet which is loaded on server startup `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` in the `init()` method of the servlet I am checking for some parameter from a properties file. If the Parameter is not there, I want to stop the Entire Context from initializing.

```
public void init(){
   Readproperty pr = new ReadProperty();
     if(!pr.parameterExists()){
     //Edit: 
     throw new UnavailableException("Testing Stopping Context")

    }
}
```

What is the best way to do this? I do now want to Move this Code to my Context Listener Class so I am looking for the best way to do it from the `init()' method.

Comment: You could throw a RuntimeException such as an IllegalStateException.

Comment: I had thought of this too but could not analyse the implication or the defference with `javax.servlet.UnavailableException`. Is there no way of calling context destruction?

Comment: Well, you're right, `init()` is allowed to throw a ServletException, so better throw an UnavailableException.

Comment: Context is still starting see me edited Answer.

Comment: And what if you throw an IllegalStateException?

Comment: Same case the Context is Starting.

Comment: I do not believe. Check again that you indeed throw the exception. Containers typically initialize webapp components sequentially and stop when any (?) exception is thrown. When spring context cannot be initialized it throws exception and context is not started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't stop a web application from starting from a servlet.

If you want to stop the web application from starting move your test(s) to a `ServletContextListener`. An exception in the `contextInitialized()` method will stop the web application from starting.

If you are using a recent Tomcat 7.0.x or 8.0.x release you can use a Tomcat specific option `failCtxIfServletStartFails` on the Context or Host that will cause the web application to fail if any of the load on startup servlets fail but this is non-standard. The `ServletContextListener` is the better option.

Comment: As I read Servlet Spec version 3.1 Section 11.6, it does *not* say the web app deployments halts when `ServletContextListener::contextInitialized` encounters an Exception. The spec only says obtusely “The container may respond to all subsequent requests to the Web application with an HTTP status code 500 to indicate an application error.” If halting is the intention of your JSR expert group, please clarify the language in upcoming Servlet 4 spec. This is a point of confusion; see [my list of similar SO questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37151007/642706). (Tomcat 8 halts, yes)

Answer (score -3):

Just throw any exception there. Initialization will be aborted.

Comment: Man this is not working see my editted Answer. Context is stillstarting

Comment: Nope. A Servlet failing to start never stops a web application from starting (at least not as per the Servlet spec anyway).